# Remover strings menores de 1 en python con regex

Tags: python

Si tengo la siguiente cadena de caracteres en python

ABC

DEF

a

GHI

como puedo crear mi expresion regular para eliminar las lineas que tengan un longitud de 1? para que quede algo asi:

ABC

DEF

GHI

Comment: creo que no hace falta usar `regex`. En ese caso puedes hacer un  `if len(cadena) != 1`

Comment: y como hago para reemplazar el contenido, es decir para que esa linea se borre

Comment: ¿Lo que tienes es una cadena multilinea (tipo `str`) o un archivo de texto, lista, etc de la que quieres eliminar ciertas líneas?

Comment: puedes por ejemplo tener `lista = ['ABC','DEF','a','GHI','b']` y para ignorar los que poseen longitud 1, `lista = [i for i in lista if len(i) != 1]]`. Si necesitas una explicación más detallada puedes editar tu pregunta agregando código y lo que hayas intentado hacer

Comment: Oh!!, the beast woke up

Comment: asi lo escribi nueva = "\n".join([i for i in s.split('\n') if len(i) != 1]) y si funciona.

pero me acabo de dar cuenta, como hago si tengo una linea con espacio? tambien cuenta la longitud de los espacio entre palabras letras y/o caracteres en mi caso necesito eliminar lineas que tengan menos 5 caracteres, pero contando solamente las letras numeros y simbolos, no se si me hago entender

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo, hay nuevas líneas entre cada grupo en tu cadena así:

```
s = "ABC\nDEF\na\nGHI"
```

Si así es, puedes hacerlo con:

```
nueva = "\n".join([i for i in s.split('\n') if len(i) != 1])
```

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta, como hago si tengo una linea con espacio? tambien cuenta la longitud de los espacio entre palabras letras y/o caracteres en mi caso necesito eliminar lineas que tengan menos 5 caracteres, pero contando solamente las letras numeros y simbolos, no se si me hago entender